# Updating tbody as div content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following table as below. The problem I have an ajax script which run as below

```
$.post('getDt.php', {a: ""}, function(data){

            $('#updateData').html(data);

         }
```

to dynamically fill the table body content into the div #updateData. Unfortunately the div is always appear on top of the table content. It never gets filled in the body section as per defined. How force it to appear in the body rather than at the top of the table?

```
 <div class="box-content">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable " style='font-size:10px;table-layout: fixed;'>
                              <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                      <th style='width: 10%;'>No.</th>
                                      <th style='width: 15%;'>NT</th>
                                      <th style='width: 20%;'>SE</th>
                                      <th style='width: 20%;'>VH</th>

                                      <th style='width: 18%;'>Status</th>
                                  </tr>
                              </thead>   
                              <tbody>
                              <div id="updateData">

                              </div>
                              </tbody>
    </div>
```

Comment: [<tbody> - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) - Look for: Permitted content

Comment: So div is not permitted right? Any solution how to overcome this issue so that I fill the content dynamically ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) element can only contain `<tr>` elements.

I suggest that you create a row (tr) and a cell (td) and place your `<div>` element within.
That is unless your data returned from your AJAX call is actual rows, then I'd move the id attribute to the `<tbody>` element and remove the `<div>` element.

```
<div class="box-content">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable " style='font-size:10px;table-layout: fixed;'>
                              <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                      <th style='width: 10%;'>No.</th>
                                      <th style='width: 15%;'>NT</th>
                                      <th style='width: 20%;'>SE</th>
                                      <th style='width: 20%;'>VH</th>

                                      <th style='width: 18%;'>Status</th>
                                  </tr>
                              </thead>   
                              <tbody id="updateData">
                              </tbody>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ok what I done now it move the entire codes starting from table into the getDt.php and get the whole table from there?

Comment: @user4126382 What do you get from getDt.php now? All you have to do is move the id="updateData" attribute to the `<tbody>` element and remove the `<div>` element :)

Comment: How if I got some of the tr as fix and only some of it I would like to update? Is that possible to use your method and how to to data?